# Solutions to earphone jack distortion

Tags: iphone, audio, ear-phones

My earphones would not longer go all the way in / click into the earphone jack on my (out of warranty) iPhone 3GS. The sound was fine but the earphones fell out with the slightest knock.

I removed some lint with a needle; now it fits but sound isn't right. It's distorted, sometimes all treble, etc. Sound is fine if I pull the earphone plug out a little bit (to the depth at which it used only be able to go) but fall out at the slightest knock.

Could there be any other reason other than lint causing this? And if so, how can I troubleshoot and resolve the problem(s)?

Comment: Have you tried other headphones?  I.e., are you sure it's not the male member... :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to do more cleaning.

Do not use metallic objects like needle.

Use toothpick.

Also use a ear-swab (with some alcohol).

Then see if you can get the sprig out in the proper position.

It is probably stuck. That's the piece that holds the plug in place.

You should see it when you look inside with flashlight and magnifier.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help you to figure out the issue since i am unsure but i do believe Apple may replace your device for you, they are generally pretty good in that regard. Give it a shot.

Comment: It's out of warranty so it'll probably be very expensive to replace, if they'll do it at all.

Comment: The 3gs is currently being sold for .01 with a contract (was free but some legality issues made it .01). I have a good friend who just went there and had a brand new ipad2 replaced with no questions asked for having a cracked screen. Point is with the phone being so cheap now and them having great customer service you cannot lose by simply trying.

Comment: I'd obviously just buy a new one for 0.01 if I could but surely that's only in the US?

Comment: I believe so but remember that's only under contract which if you were renewing you may as well get the current model. Unkess for some reason you wished to stick with the 3GS.

Comment: http://bit.ly/yUqt9F again may just be for the US but there is a link in any event.